# Check if post visited first time

Tags: php, functions

How to check if post visited first time? If post already never visited by nobody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, use of custom meta field to do that.
In `functions.php` put this:

```
// add the tracker in your header by using wp_footer hook
function is_viewed ($post_id) {

    if ( !is_single() ) return;


/*

At times queries performed in other templates such as sidebar.php may corrupt certain conditional tags. 
For instance, in header.php a conditional tag works properly but doesn't work in a theme's footer.php.
The trick is to put wp_reset_query before the conditional test in the footer.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#In_a_theme.27s_footer.php_file

*/
    wp_reset_query();

    if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    if ( !has_views($post_id) ){

        // This post is visited for the first time

        // add post meta to mark this post as viewed
        add_post_meta($post_id,'viewed', "YES", true);
     }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'is_viewed');

function has_views($post_id){
  if (!get_post_meta($post_id,'viewed',true)) return false;
  else return true;
}
```

then you can use `has_views($post_id)` anywhere you want to test if post is visited for the first time or not

Comment: I add this code in end of functions.php and some js elements (like admin bar) stopped work. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. There was a mistake in my code. I have corrected it and updated the answer.

Comment: Great! It's works! Thank you!

Comment: @Martin please see the update answer.

Comment: thank you! Code is work perfect. I add them via Ad Inserter plugin after post.